# Passing by ref not working when using Replace on string

Tags: c#

I just started learning C# and I am trying to understand how to use the ref and out .
I tried to build the simplest function I could think of but I'm getting error and I can't understand why.

```
namespace cscheck
{
   class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        string check = "Check noob wallak";
        Console.WriteLine(check);
        swap(ref check, "noob", "boon");
        Console.WriteLine(check);
     }

     static void swap(ref string origin ,string x,  string y)
     {
       origin.Replace(x, y);
     }
   }
}
```

But the results I get are :

> Check noob wallak
>
> Check noob wallak

As I understand x and y are passed by value while check passed by reference,  but the replace hasn't ouccred and I can figure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Replace` doesn't mutate, it creates a new string. Try:

```
origin = origin.Replace(x, y);
```

Comment: I'm quite disappointed from myself that I didn't thought about that.
thank you for the fast reply ,and also to the 2 others.

Answer (score 2):

`Replace()` returns a string. You must use it as the result as so :

```
origin = origin.Replace(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.Replace` returns a new string, it does not modify the original. Strings are immutable.